# Exception in thread “main” org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field startId in _1, _2;

Tags: scala, apache-spark

0

I have 2 case class as below:

```
  case class IcijAddressRaw(
                             node_id: Option[Long],
                             name: Option[String],
                             address: Option[String],
                             country_codes: Option[String],
                             countries: Option[String],
                             sourceID: Option[String],
                             valid_until: Option[String],
                             note: Option[String]
                           )

  case class IcijEdgesRaw(
                           START_ID: Option[Long],
                           TYPES: Option[String],
                           END_ID: Option[Long],
                           link: Option[String],
                           start_date: Option[java.sql.Date],
                           end_date: Option[java.sql.Date],
                           sourceID: Option[String],
                           valid_until: Option[String]
                         )
```

I join both data sets with the above case class as below:

```
val addressWithEdgesDS = addressRawDS
  .joinWith(edgesRawDS, edgesRawDS("END_ID") === addressRawDS("node_id"), "inner")

val addressGroupDS = addressWithEdgesDS.groupByKey { fullAddress => fullAddress}.mapGroups {
  case (startId, fullAddress) =>
    (startId, fullAddress.toSeq)
}


def thirdPartyWithAddressDS = thirdPartyDS
  .joinWith(addressGroupDS, thirdPartyDS("thirdPartyId") === addressGroupDS("_2.startId"), "left_outer")
  .map{
    case (thirdParty,null) => thirdParty
    case (thirdParty, (thirdPartyId, addressSeq)) => thirdParty.copy(addresses = addressSeq.map(addressCaseClassMap[ThirdPartyCC]))
  }
```

I can gradle build the jar without problem. However, when I run the below script:

```
 ./runQSS.sh -s com.quantexa.academytask.etl.projects.icij.CreateCaseClass -e local -r etl.icij -c /home/training-admin/academy-task/application.conf
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field startId in _1, _2;
```

I have tried the column name "START_ID" as well as"_2.START_ID" but same error. My understanding is that this joined datasets struct need to use _1 or _2 to refer to the left or right dataset column. But in this case, it seems failed to point to the correct column.

my joined schema as below: scala> addressWithEdgesDS.printSchema() root

```
 |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- node_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country_codes: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- countries: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sourceID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- valid_until: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- note: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- START_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TYPES: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- END_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- start_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sourceID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- valid_until: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: The Error message is clear, which says It could not find the column `startId`  inside `_2` in dataser `addressGroupDS`. Make sure the dataset `addressGroupDS` have column `_2.startId` .

Comment: @ShankarKoirala  it is resolved as below:     val addressGroupDS = addressWithEdgesDS.groupByKey(_._2.START_ID).mapGroups{
      case (startId, fullAddress) =>
        (startId, fullAddress.toSeq)
    }